# adding to a string without commas

Tags: python

I want to add things to a string without any commas.

I have a string URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/feed_str?max-results=max_result&time=

```
feed_str = top_rated
max_result = 5
time_str = today
web_str = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/",feed_str, "?max-results=" ,max_result,"&time=" + time_str
```

it prints like this

```
('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/', 'top_rated', '?max-results=', '5', '&time=today')
```

and I want it to print like this:

```
('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?max-results=5'&time=today')
```

which is just one string. Any help?!

Comment: The clue is already in your code. Look at your output. What's different about the way you use the variable `time_str` in your string construction?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint ; you are looking for a way to `concatenate` strings.

Answer (score 2):

String **concatenation** is what you are looking for and SO has many threads on this topic ( [String concatenation vs. string substitution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376461/string-concatenation-vs-string-substitution-in-python) , [Concatenation Operator + or ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033242/concatenation-operator-or) ,...)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the commas on the `web_str` and put the signal `'+'` in their places.

Comment: Yes, very good. However, most people think it's better to offer hints for [tag:homework] questions, rather than answering them directly, since this gives the questioner a chance to learn, rather than just complete assignments. See [How to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for more.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. Didn't see that was a homework question. I'll pay more attention next time. Thank you for advise.