# Why does string concatenation matter in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've seen a good number of posts (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033242/concatenation-operator-or) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842779/string-concatenation-without-operator-in-python)) speaking about concatenation in Python, how best to do it ('+' vs ','), which is faster, etc. But I can't seem to find out **why** it matters. Roger Pate mentioned in the first example about passing multiple arguments vs one, but I'm still unclear.

So, why does concatenation matter? What is a use case where this would be critical?

Comment: `,` doesn't do concatenation in Python.

Comment: ^ this is where it is critical I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable objects in Python, so you cannot modify existing strings. That means that every concatenation of a string results in a new string object being created and two (the source objects) being thrown away. Memory allocation is expensive enough to make this matter a lot.

So when you know you need to concatenate multiple strings, store them in a list. And then at the end, just once, join that list using `''.join(list_of_strings)`. That way, a new string will only be created once.

Note that this also applies in other languages. For example Java and C# both have a `StringBuilder` type which is essentially the same. As long as you keep appending new string parts, they will just internally add that to a string, and only when you convert the builder into a real string, the concatenation happens—and again just once.

Also note, that this memory allocation overhead already happens when you just append a few strings in a single line. For example `a + b + c + d` will create three intermediary strings. You can see that, if you look at the byte code for that expression:

```
>>> dis.dis('a + b + c + d')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a) 
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b) 
              6 BINARY_ADD           
              7 LOAD_NAME                2 (c) 
             10 BINARY_ADD           
             11 LOAD_NAME                3 (d) 
             14 BINARY_ADD           
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Each `BINARY_ADD` concats the two previous values and creates a new object for the result on the stack. Note that for constant string literals, the compiler is smart enough to notice that you are adding constants:

```
>>> dis.dis('"foo" + "bar" + "baz"')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ('foobarbaz') 
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you do have some variable parts within that though—for example if you want to produce a nicely formatted output—then you are back to creating intermediary string objects. In that case, using `str.format` is a good idea, e.g. `'foo {} bar {} baz'.format(a, b)`.

Answer (score 6):

Because in general `+`ing `n` strings will result in `n-1` allocations of `O(n)` memory for the result. Concatenation via adjacency is done in the parser, and performs 1 allocation. Concatenation via for instance `''.join(iter(s))` will perform `O(log(n))` allocations/copies of `2n` total memory.

```
> a = ['a'] * 100000
> def concat(strings):
      c = ''
      for s in strings:
          c += s
      return c
> %timeit ''.join(a)       # precalculates necessary buffer size
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
> %timeit ''.join(iter(a)) # allocates exponentially larger buffers
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 ms per loop
> %timeit concat(a)        # allocates a new buffer n-1 times
100 loops, best of 3: 7.15 ms per loop
```

Comment: I love this answer, especially for the timing information

Comment: great answer ... Im not sure the loop is identical to `s=a+b+c...` but awesome nonetheless (but i think that `s=a+b+c...` is essentially the same as `''.join(...)`)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I know that the JVM will optimize my concat method to use a mutable buffer, I'm not sure whether or not python performs the same optimization but it's certainly possible.

Comment: I had always assumed `join()` would walk the list once to sum the lengths of the items being joined and do one allocation, then walk again to assemble into the newly allocated space.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It seems you are correct! `%timeit ''.join(a) -> 1.07 ms/loop`, `%timeit ''.join(iter(a)) -> 201 ms/loop`